# Prepend and append content based on browser size

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, addeventlistener, prepend

I have this function that moves a HTML element around the DOM based on whether the window size is less than 640px or more. I'm moving the image with **prepend** and **append**, but because the function fires every time the window is resized I think I'm asking for performance issues.

The code:

```
function moveDealsImage() {

    var mobile_width = 640;
    var wi = $(window).width();

    if (wi < mobile_width) {
        $( ".deals-header" ).prepend( $("div.htp") );
    } else {
        $( ".deals-header" ).append( $("div.htp") );
    }
}
window.addEventListener("resize", moveDealsImage);
moveDealsImage();
```

I need to keep the listener in there.

Is there a way to do that, but then only prepending/appending the element **once** each time that the if or else statements become true? (instead of it happening on every pixel change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you can do to optimize this.

A first option is to only execute your moveDealsImage function when the state changes from mobile to desktop or reverse. All the other resizes can just be ignored.

This can be accomplished by using something like following code:

```
var mobile_width = 640;
var is_mobile = (window.innerWidth <= mobile_width);
function moveDealsImage(e) {

    // Only execute the function when then state changes from mobile to desktop or reverse
    if( 
        ! is_mobile && window.innerWidth > mobile_width || 
        is_mobile && window.innerWidth <= mobile_width 
    )
        return;

    // Update state
    is_mobile = (window.innerWidth <= mobile_width);

    console.log('your code here');
}
window.addEventListener("resize", moveDealsImage);
moveDealsImage();
```

Another and better solution would be to use CSS media queries. This can be done with the following CSS and HTML.

```
.desktop-deals-header {
   display: block;
}
.mobile-deals-header {
   display: none;
}

@media only screen 
and (max-width : 640px) {
   .desktop-deals-header {
      display: none;
   }
   .mobile-deals-header {
      display: block
   }
}
```

and in your HTML you add two headers, one for desktop and one for mobile.

```
<div class="mobile-deals-header">Mobile header</div>
<div class="desktop-deals-header">Desktop header</div>
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks Wim.

I've already got the CSS solution in place, I just wanted to explore how to do it with JS, and your code does it brilliantly, cheers!